# How to get data from a Svelte store to +page.js?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

In the `+page.svelte` I import my store `import { authStore } from '../stores/authStore';` and then I can access the user ID from the store like this:

```
let uid;
authStore.subscribe((curr) => {
    uid = curr?.currentUser?.uid;
});
```

But how can I access it in the `+page.js`? `console.log('uid: ', uid);` will give me `uid: undefined`

OK, I can store it in the cookies but that is not that secure.

Comment: "I can store it in the cookies but that is not that secure." That is completely wrong, it's what cookies are for. (They still have to be used correctly, though, making them `HttpOnly` for one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're actually trying to do, but variables aren't shared between page.svelte and page.js by default, so of course `uid` is going to be undefined in page.js. You could just subscribe to it in page.js exactly like you were doing in page.svelte:

```js
authStore.subscribe((curr) => {
    uid = curr?.currentUser?.uid;
});
```

However, the typical reason to even have a page.js file is to populate the data needed for page.svelte by means of a load function which gets called first. So you probably want to do something more along the lines of:

```js
import { get } from 'svelte/store';
import authStore from './stores'

export const load = async () => {
    return get(authStore); // gets the current value
}
```

And then in your page.svelte you can import that data like so:

```
<script>
    export let data;
    console.log(data); // contains whatever load() returned, so the value of authStore
</script>
```

Again, there's not a lot of detail in your question that would explain *why* you want to get the value of authStore in the .js rather than in the .svelte file, so it's hard to say if that even makes sense.